# VS.NET 2015 Auto Complete / add brackets

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Today I installed VS.NET 2015 and thought here are many good features, but I am having issues with several basic features I had in VS2013. I am not sure how I could bring them back.

A simple example, using VB.NET in VS 2015, I write

```
msg.ShowError "This is my error"
```

and when I hit enter, it auto adds brackets to it and make it look like this

```
msg.ShowError ("This is my error")
```

But now, it doesn't do that, and I have to manually add brackets.

Similarly, if I write something like

```
lblExported.Text = "This is
```

It doesn't close the quote automatically, as it was doing in VS2013 and before

```
lblExported.Text = "This is"
```

Any idea how to configure it to behave like old way?
I tried enabling 
Tools->Options and from the dialog, Text Editor->All Languages->Automatic brace complete, but that didn't worked. Interesting part is that when I save and then re-open the dialog, this checkbox goes back into mixed state.

Thank you

Comment: you're potentially missing some productivity tool addons that you have installed in 2013, that aren't in 2015

Comment: No Sir, I don't. I never used any productivity tool. It was just simple things from all versions back,